# Loading array using loops

Tags: vb.net

firstly this is not exactly a problem but more like a quiz. I have 3 arrays which I will load data into from a dataset, in the future this set of data might expand and the code will get excessively long, how can I load the data as seen below using loops without using additional array?

```
 Dim ds as dataset = objDashBoardStats.DashBoard_TotalSales_Static_Get(objDashBoardStats)

                Dim statvals(11) As Integer
                statvals = LoadData(statvals, ds.Tables(0))

                Dim statvalsMen(3), statvalsWomen(3), statvalsUnknown(3) As Integer

                statvalsMen(0) = statvals(0)
                statvalsWomen(0) = statvals(1)
                statvalsUnknown(0) = statvals(2)
                statvalsMen(1) = statvals(3)
                statvalsWomen(1) = statvals(4)
                statvalsUnknown(1) = statvals(5)
                statvalsMen(2) = statvals(6)
                statvalsWomen(2) = statvals(7)
                statvalsUnknown(2) = statvals(8)
                statvalsMen(3) = statvals(9)
                statvalsWomen(3) = statvals(10)
                statvalsUnknown(3) = statvals(11)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know VB explicitly, but it should be similar to this:

```
int max = statvals.size; //just get the amount of indexes in statvals. max%3 should be 0
for(int i=0; i<max; i+=3)
{
  statvalsMen(i/3) = statvals(i);
  statvalsWomen(i/3) = statvals(i+1);
  statvalsUnknown(i/3) = statvals(i+2);
}
```

Comment: fix with `statvalsMen(i/3)` such that it increments on every 3rd iteration.

Comment: Thanks, forgot about that. I would also make it floor(i/3) but I'm not sure if C has that (I'm a Java/C# person)

Answer (score 0):

Loop from the Dataset instead of using the other array (assumes there will be an equal number of records in the table for Men, Women, and Unknown as the question indicates)...

```
    Dim intTotalPerCategory As Integer = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count / 3

    Dim statvalsMen(intTotalPerCategory), statvalsWomen(intTotalPerCategory), _
        statvalsUnknown(intTotalPerCategory) As Integer

    For i = 0 To (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1) Step 3

        'Change "NameOfColumn" to the correct column name or ordinal number.
        statvalsMen(i) = CInt(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("NameOfColumn"))
        statvalsWomen(i + 1) = CInt(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("NameOfColumn"))
        statvalsUnknown(i + 2) = CInt(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("NameOfColumn"))

    Next
```

Comment: Your question asked for a solution that does not use the other array.  This solution will work so long as LoadData isn't doing more than just loading the field from that table in the dataset into the array...if its doing extra processing to load that array, then you will have to loop from the array (or change your LoadData method).